# Calling a class method in another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, class-method

I have a class like following

```
Class ViewControlelr: UIViewController {
    func instantiateDocumentSubPartNavigationVC(documentPart: DocumentPart, documentPartsArray: [DocumentPart]) {
//definition
}
}
```

In other class called ViewController2, I wanna call above method.
I expect to see below so I can pass parameters to the method in ViewController2

```
ViewController.instantiateDocumentSubPartNavigationVC(documentPart: DocumentPart, documentPartsArray: [DocumentPart])
```

But what I actually see is

```
ViewController.instantiateDocumentSubPartNavigationVC(ViewController)
```

How can I successfully utilize the class method in different class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions can be declared to operate at one of two levels - class or instance. When you call a function, you have to match correctly.

Currently your code has `ViewController.instantiateDocumentSubPartNavigationVC`, and `ViewController` is a class, not an instance of a class. This does not match the function, which is declared to operate on an instance (since it doesn't have the keyword `class` or `static`).

So either you need to use an instance of a `ViewController` (which might be `viewController` with a little 'l'), or declare the function with `class`. The choice depends on what you're trying to do, but it's most likely the first option.

This is why your question got marked as duplicate - because it looks like you want to call one class-level function from another class-level function, but I suspect that's not what you're after.

Comment: If I make it as class function, I find that I can't call self.presentViewController(rootViewController, animated: true, completion: nil). What would be the problem?

Comment: I will update to try to explain better.